# Configurar LAN en equipo local para ser accedido desde las api de mi app movil

Tags: xampp

Es posible configurar de manera lan donde con xampp levanto mi proyecto en laravel (es un api) y conectado a traves de la misma red mi equipo celular me gustaría conectarme a la app levantada en xampp, debo realizar una configuración adicional? la verdad ando bastande desorientado, una ayuda se agradeceria bastante

Comment: Si es posible, nada especial que hacer, en el móvil debes conectarte usando la IP local de la LAN de la máquina donde tienes corriendo el servicio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se que es un poco tarde pero lo que me funciono bastante fue lo siguiente:

**OJO LO PROBÉ SOLO CON LARAVEL EN EL BACKEND, PARA PODER CREAR UNA RED LAN "DE MANERA RAPIDA Y SENCILLA" FUE COMPARTIR INTERNET DESDE MI CELULAR AL NOTEBOOK Y REALICE LA SIGUIENTE CONFIGURACIÓN**

1) Averiguar el dominio y dirección local en la que trabajamos en el pc con apache.

Ignoro como es en Linux así que por ende lo explicare para Windows. Sin embargo, entiendo que es igual de sencillo hacerlo.
- Vayan a su boton inicio y escriban "cmd" (en windows 8 apreten la tecla windows + r y escriban "cmd"). Esto sin las comillas.
- Escriban en la consola "ipconfig" (de nuevo sin comillas)

Verán algo como esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver. En mi caso me muevo por el dominio "192.168.1.x". Eso quiere decir que cualquier computador que este en mi red local tomara cualquier numero X (generalmente están por orden de conexión) y que la dirección interna del equipo donde esta apache es la "192.168.1.2".

Para el siguiente paso necesitamos saber el dominio (por ponerle un nombre)

2) Configurar Apache para que trabaje en modo local.

Abran el archivo httpd.conf en la carpeta de apache y busquen lo siguiente. (Mi versión es la 2.4.2)

```
#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
# Online --> Require all granted

#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove

Require local
```

El "Require local" significa que solo se vera en su computador. Si lo cambian por "require all granted" haran que su host se vea en toda internet. No queremos eso. Cierto?

Necesitamos habilitar apache para toda su red y el modo local (vale decir. Los pc's que agarra su router). Por ende necesitamos agregar la linea "Require ip 192.168.1" ya que, en mi caso, me muevo por ese dominio (si el tuyo es distinto, ya sabes!)

Quedaría entonces así:

```
#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
# Online --> Require all granted

#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove

Require local
Require ip 192.168.1
```

Reinician su servidor (cierren y luego inicien wamp, xampp o lo que usen para esto) y traten de conectarse desde su movil o tablet a la dirección interna. en mi caso coloco en la barra de dirección del navegador del tablet "192.168.1.2".

Guala!! Cargo la carpeta root!! Sin embargo, si trato de entrar al dominio de mi app no lo conseguire. Por que?

3) Compatibilizar el virtualhost para poder ser visto

En apache ustedes hicieron un virtualhost para poder entrar directamente a su proyecto y tuvieron que modificar el archivo host. Eso existe en Android e Iphone pero requieren permisos de root (en el caso de Android) y es engorroso para hacer un test. Lo otro sería hacer un servidor dns local. Que engorroso!!

Sin embargo. Para aquello existe xip.io! Este servicio crea automaticamente el dns y permite probar la aplicación en modo local facilmente.

Necesitamos abrir el httpd-vhost.conf que modificamos para laravel. El mio esta mas o menos así.

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "c:/Users/xxx/Dropbox/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/localhost-access.log" common

DocumentRoot "c:/Users/XXX/Dropbox/wamp/www/proyecto/public"
    ServerName app.dev

La primera parte es para no perder el "127.0.0.1" o "localhost" pero no tiene que ver con este tutorial. El segundo es el importante ya que hace que al ir en el navegador a "app.dev" me cargue mi proyecto laravel. Recordemos que también hay que ajustar el archivo host.

Pues bien. Con xip.io nos olvidamos de ese asunto. Tienen que colocar una linea más. "ServerAlias app.*.xip.io". Quedaría así.

DocumentRoot "c:/Users/XXX/Dropbox/wamp/www/proyecto/public"
    ServerName app.dev
    ServerAlias app.*.xip.io

Guardan, cierran su server y lo abren de nuevo!

Ahora vayan a su tablet y coloquen lo que pusieron en ServerAlias pero cambiando el "*" por la dirección de su pc donde esta apache. En mi caso sería "app.192.168.1.2.xip.io".

Listo! Obviamente existen formas de fijar la dirección IP y de maquillar esa dirección pero la cosa es que para probar funciona y muy bien!

fuente: https://laraveles.com/foro/viewtopic.php?id=786

Answer (score 0):

Una forma más rápida y fácil para servir tu aplicación en una red local, es usar el mismo comando `serve` especificando la IP local de tu equipo (puedes averiguarla con ipconfig) y el puerto (80 en este caso):

```
php artisan serve --host 192.168.1.12 --port 80
```

Si lo quisieras hacer en Linux solamente añades el `sudo` antes de todo el comando (esto es para poder servir en el puerto 80).

Y en los demás equipos ya solo simplemente escribirías la IP local de tu equipo y listo, eso es todo.